# How can I quickly switch between JDKs in cygwin?

Tags: java, bash, cygwin, java-6

When working on the command line (using CYGWIN), I frequently need to switch between different versions of java. Are there any utilities that can take care of setting up JAVA_HOME, PATH etc. for me each time I need to switch?

Comment: JAVA_HOME, PATH, etc. are environment variables.  If you run a program from the command line, the program can change its own environment and those changes will be inherited by any process that it spawns, but it has no ability to change the environment of the shell that started it.  I would create a shell-script that I could `source` from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a shell (bash, ksh, ...) function for this;  Functions execute in the context of the current shell process and therefore *can* affect its environment:

```
# Switch current JDK (JAVA_HOME) on Cygwin
function jdkswitch {
    local version=$1
    local -a JDKS
    JDKS[8]='/cygdrive/c/apps/JDK/x64/jdk1.8.0_231'
    JDKS[11]='/cygdrive/c/apps/JDK/x64/jdk-11.0.5'

    if [[ -z ${version} ]] ; then
        echo "Current JDK: ${JAVA_HOME}"
        echo "Available JDKs: ${JDKS[*]}"
    else
        local jdkhome=${JDKS[${version}]}
        if [[ -d ${jdkhome} ]] ; then
            # Cygwin paths do not work for JAVA_HOME, must use Windows-style
            export JAVA_HOME=$(cygpath -w ${jdkhome})
            PATH=${jdkhome}/bin:${PATH}
            echo "Switched JDK to:"
            java -version
        else
            echo "Usage: jdkswitch version"
            echo "Available versions: ${!JDKS[*]}"
        fi
    fi
}
```

I typically save my functions one-per-file in ~/bin/functions and load them in  my .profile (bash lacks the ksh "autoload" feature):

```
FPATH=~/bin/functions
for FUNC in ${FPATH}/* ; do
    . ${FUNC}
done
```

Then to switch JDK it's simply:

```
$ jdkswitch 11
```

*There's a minor bug there where successive switches will prepend to the PATH each time, it might be fixable with some trickery but I've not experienced a problem to-date.*

As an aside (since the question specifies Cygwin), here is a MacOS version:

```
# Switch current JDK (JAVA_HOME) based on available Mac installs
function jdkswitch {
    local version=$1
    local jdkhome
    if [[ -z ${version} ]] ; then
        /usr/libexec/java_home --verbose
    else
        jdkhome=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v${version})
        if [[ -d ${jdkhome} ]] ; then
            export JAVA_HOME=${jdkhome}
            echo "Switched to ${JAVA_HOME}"
            java -version
        fi
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://sdkman.io/install allows for quick switching between JDK versions and is compatible with cygwin